# Why am I getting an error for specified expression in a Query?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I keep getting the following error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression '[Employees}.{Last Name] & "," & [First Name]' as part of an aggregate function.

This is the SQL View:

```
SELECT [Employees].[Last Name] & ", " & [First Name] AS EmployeeName,
       Sum(IIf([Vacation Calendar].[TypeID]=1,[Vacation Calendar].[Time],0)) AS SumOfSickTime
FROM   Employees 
INNER 
JOIN   [Vacation Calendar] 
       ON Employees.ID = [Vacation Calendar].EmployeeID
WHERE  (((Employees.[Active Employee])=True))
ORDER 
BY     [Employees].[Last Name] & ", " & [First Name];
```

Comment: Why not use the `EmployeeName` alias in the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using SUM so you need to include a GROUP BY function at the end of your query.

Something like GROUP BY [Employees].[Last Name] & ", " & [First Name]
using ORDER BY  wont fix this

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help